# Records with empty fields not showing in MS access query

Tags: ms-access, field, record

I have multiple Inner joined tables that i can summon with  a query however there is a certain field that sometimes can be Null, when i use query to summon records it will only show records that already have that certain field populated.
So how to show the records that have other conditions full filled whether it have empty fields or dont have any ??

I have the table Employee with one to one relation with company car licence plate Number. some employees might not have assigned car. The CARS has a separate table so the following example for two record scenarios :

```
SocialNo | FirstName | LastName | LicencePlate | Other  
14256335 | John      | Wick     | 213546       | bla bla  
12348596 | Sara      | Milles   |              | bla bla  
18596563 | Leo       | Cranes   | 185647       | bla bla
```

In my case the licence in my country is just numbers and of course i cant have duplicates of the same car for different employees. But employees with no cars will be left blank. If i were to make a query to show all records only John and Leo will appear and if i add like 0 Licence for every employee with no car will create duplicates which will violate the 1-to-1 relation.

And so for any query i will make as long as i inner joining between the two tables.

```
SELECT SocialNo ,FirstName, LastName, Car.LicenceID From Employees
Inner Join Car On Employees.Licence=Car.LicenceID 
Where ( Car.LicenceID=[Forms]![EmployeesQuery]![LicenceCombo]
    Or [Forms]![EmployeesQuery]![LicenceCombo] Is Null)
```

Solution is to make LEFT Join instead of inner join.

Comment: Need to show sample data and desired result as text tables. Also show the attempted query SQL statement.

Comment: I edited the question with and example.

Comment: Do you get what you want if your change the query from `INNER JOIN` to `LEFT JOIN`?

Comment: Is field name in Employees Licence or LicencePlate? INNER JOIN requires matching records in both tables. Use LEFT or RIGHT JOIN instead if you want all records from one table.

Comment: Inner join require matching Fields in both table not records correct me if i am wrong.The filed named Licence inEmployee table and LicenceID in the car table ,changing the names gave the same results.

Comment: I dont really know how to use LEFT and RIGHT Join properly but i dont , i understand their concept but i dont see how will i benefit from that. if u can give an example i might try here it will be helpful

Comment: Yup LEFT Join solved my problems thanks HandsUp.